# StockTwits API Streaming and Search Used Like Twitter Streaming

Tags: stocktwits

The StockTwits API documentation describes steams in a way that sounds like static search results, for example streams/symbol:

```
This allows an API application to search for a symbol or user. 30 Results will be a  
combined list of symbols and users.
```

This seems similar to search/symbols:

```
This allows an API application to search for a symbol directly. 30 Results will return
only ticker symbols.
```

Other than the fact that search excludes users, I don't see the difference.

In contrast, the Twitter API provides methods to request a continuous stream of tweets, which I have gotten to provide tens of thousands of tweets in a few days.

Is it possible to have StockTwit pump tweets continuously, similar to Twitter?

If so, what is required? Since StockTwit streaming looks like searching to me, the only option I have seen is to submit repeated search requests, but that would exhaust the rate limit.

I prefer C#, but I am glad to study answers in other languages, such as PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a static search for symbols or both symbols and users as a combined search. This isn't a streaming search endpoint for filtering content. This is strictly for use for finding a symbol or a user to go directly to the stream.

We are looking into offering **streaming endpoints** and search would be part of this offering.

Comment: Are we able to search streams yet? Not really interested in searching the usernames and stock symbols as much as I am searching content via freeform regular expressions and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using [streamdata.io](http://streamdata.io/) which allows to stream any APIs. We have already implemented a StockTwits demo, which can be found [here](https://github.com/streamdataio/StockTwits-Android) and explanations can be found in this [blog post](http://streamdata.io/blog/android-stocktwits-real-time-feed/).

I think it's quite easy to transpose what has been done with Android to the C# world. All you need is an [EventSource](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/) library and a [JSON-Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/#c-35) library.